# list indices must be integers or slices not str python

Tags: python

```
@classmethod
def RoundToValidQuantity(cls, symbol_data, desired_quantity, round_up: bool = False) -> Decimal:
    """ Returns the minimum quantity of a symbol we can buy,
    closest to desiredPrice """

    lot_filter = {}

    for fil in symbol_data["filters"]:
        if fil["filterType"] == "LOT_SIZE":
            lot_filter = fil
            break
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I need you help please

Comment: Are symbol_data and fil lists or dictionnaries ?

Comment: I need to know what is symbol_data, however it looks like you a lists inside symbol_data and not dictionaries, so you can't do fil["filterType"] since the is list and list indices cannot be str.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your list is comprised of numbers and non-numbers. In Python, you can only access a list directly by providing integer indexes.

To avoid this issue, use the `enumerate()` function. This provides a list of tuples containing your value and an index you can use to access your list.

```
list = [1, 2, "a", "b", 3, 4, "c", "d"]

for index, value in enumerate(list):
  print("the index is: " + index)
  print("the value is: " + value)
```

Expected output:

```
the index is: 0
the value is: 1

the index is: 1
the value is: 2

the index is: 2
the value is: a

the index is: 3
the value is b
```

etc.

EDIT:

If you're using a dictionary, you have to declare it using curly brackets:

```
>>> my_dict = {}
```

Then you can add fields to it like so:

```
>>> my_dict["field_name"] = "blah"
```

and access it like so:

```
>>> my_dict["field_name"]
'blah'
```